# Can't find cols_add in gt

Tags: r, shiny, gt

I couldn't find some functions like cols_add, row_group_order, rows_add.. (may be more)
If I run code with cols_add, there are error 'could not find function 'cols_add'"
I want to know.. is it my fault? or is it problem so need to report?

this is website of gt (about cols_add)
https://gt.rstudio.com/reference/cols_add.html

this is part of index of the result > library(help = 'gt')

```
cells_title             Location helper for targeting the table title
                        and subtitle
cols_align              Set the alignment of columns
cols_align_decimal      Align all numeric values in a column along the
                        decimal mark
cols_hide               Hide one or more columns
cols_label              Relabel one or more columns
cols_label_with         Relabel columns with a function
cols_merge              Merge data from two or more columns to a single
                        column
cols_merge_n_pct        Merge two columns to combine counts and
                        percentages
cols_merge_range        Merge two columns to a value range column
cols_merge_uncert       Merge columns to a value-with-uncertainty
                        column
cols_move               Move one or more columns
cols_move_to_end        Move one or more columns to the end
cols_move_to_start      Move one or more columns to the start
cols_unhide             Unhide one or more columns
cols_width              Set the widths of columns
countrypops             Yearly populations of countries from 1960 to
                        2021
```

I think I do my best but i'm beginner of R.. so if there are anything I can please let me know...

thank you

Comment: I believe that these missing functions are in the [development version](https://github.com/rstudio/gt/pull/1367) of `gt`, not the version installed via CRAN.

Comment: I don’t understand why you don’t report it to the package maintainer. The documentation authors are using the version numbers for the CRAN hosted package. Which has been 0.9.0 since 3/2023

Comment: I thought the naming convention usage was poorly done. If they’re going to add functions, they should increment the version labels in the docs on GitHub. At any rate the OP should use `devtools::install_github("rstudio/gt")`

Comment: @neilfws oh my god I can't believe I forgot to check pull request.. I see. Because there are information about cols_add in the site, I think it can use my version. thank you so much.

Comment: @IRTFM Thank you. I check once again now, there are 'Function Introduced' and 'In Development'.. it's my mistake .. anyway, thank you for answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`cols_add` was merged into the master branch of the `gt` repository (at the time of writing) four days ago](https://github.com/rstudio/gt/pull/1367), so it seems to have not made its way into the CRAN version yet. But after installing the development version via Github, it is there:

```
devtools::install_github("rstudio/gt")
gt::cols_add

# function (.data, ..., .before = NULL, .after = NULL) 
# {
# etc.
```